Stability of stationary points
In the article by Hirsch "On stability of stationary points of transformation groups
It's mentioned that $0$ is a stable stationary point of the diffeomorphism $f(x)=x+x^3$ (stationary point of the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}$). The definition of the stability is given as follows: the group of $C^1$ diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is endowed with compact-open topology (and not the strong Whitney topology), i.e. the topology of the uniform convergence of diffeomorphisms and their first derivatives on compact sets and the space of continuous homomorphisms $A(G,\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is endowed with compact-open topology too.

Is it possible to use the stability of the transversality: if the graph of a smooth map $f$ is transverse to the diagonal (i.e. $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $D_xf$ in any fixed point) then any $1$-parameter family of maps homotopics to $f$ still transverse to the diagonal. Is it true that a diffeomorphism sufficiently close to $f$ is homotopic to $f$ ?


How to prove that any $C^1$ diffeomorphism close to $f(x)=x+x^3$ has a stationary point near $0$, even though the graph of $f$ is not transverse to the diagonal ?


The definition of being stable is here topological rather than dynamical which gives more flexibility (but perhaps also makes it less useful). Even under a $C^0$ perturbation $0$ is a stable fixed point of $f(x)=x+x^3$. Given $\epsilon>0$, in order to assure a fixed point $p$ of $f+h$ with $|p|<\epsilon$ all you need is to pick say $\delta = \epsilon^3$
and ask for $|h|<\delta$ (locally) uniformly. Then $(f+h)(\epsilon) - \epsilon > 0$ and
$(f+h)(-\epsilon) +\epsilon < 0$ which suffices for the existence of such a $p$.
As said in the article the fixed point need not be unique. In fact you may
find a small $C^\infty$ perturbations of $f$ which will have infinitely many fixed points in any neighborhood of $0$, e.g. something of the form: $h=\delta \exp(-1/x^2) \sin(1/x^2)$.
For your first question, I think you need more precise definitions regarding how to define the homotopy and the class of $f$ considered.
Most likely the answer is No. In the present formulation you have to worry about what happens when going to infinity. Given a transversal $f$ you may have a sequence of fixed points going to infinity but becoming less and less transversal. Depending on your definitions, under a small uniform $\delta$-perturbation fixed points far away may disappear and under a homotopy, some fixed points further and further away may still get lost. You could here perhaps save it by introducing a notion of being uniformly transversal but this does not seem to be part of the original problem. The second part of that question should also be formulated more precisely.
